# Excel Power Pivot Related DAX function is Returning Blanks

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerpivot

[Data View of Table where function is inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MI3.png)

Hi,

I'm using Power Query and Power Pivot in an attempt to automate reconciliations.
The goal is to first identify reference numbers found in a supplier statement and then lookup 3 fields such as Payment Due Date and Aging Analysis on our records.

To do this I've created a relationship between two tables, the first being called SAP Basis of Comparison and the second table is called Supplier Statement. The primary key and foreign key are Reference Number.[Relationship View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3BRI.png)

The problem is that when I used the =RELATED() DAX function, the function returns blanks and I don't know why.

SOS. Please Help

Comment: I don't think you need the related, just pull the column name from the table that you used in the relationship.

Comment: It might be possible that Reference number is a STRING in both tables and may be that needs to be TRIM,CLEAN,PROPER to  move any space in between before doing a RELATED.

Comment: the setup looks correct, I would follow @smpa01 advice. The column type & content have to be exactly the same for the join to work e.g. "123   "<>"123 ", same as 123<>"123"